# Comparing tables cell by cell

Tags: excel, vba, compare

I would like to compare two tables on a cell by cell bases. The difficulty is, however, that Information is always row-based meaning that Information in one row belongs together. It can theoretically happen that only single cells of a row are modified in the second (newer) table. Also, it can happen that new rows are added either at the end of the table or in between. I tried to concatenate all cells of one row into one Cell and then to compare these between the two tables, however, that is limited to 256 characters which are not enough for a complete row. At least in this way, I can detector new rows in the second table. Unfortunately, this does not work for the detection of differences on a  Cell level. Does anybody have an idea? Thanks a lot in advance. Best wishes, Hansi

Comment: I forgot to say hello ;-)

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: Unless the rows don't have fixed IDs or similar this will be a super tough or even impossible action in case new rows are added in between the table (there might be some workaround if you know which rows have been added). Please provide files/expected outcome